# how to open PDF URL into the app without downloading in ionic 5

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, download, ionic-native, ionic5

i am already try with this plugin but no luck

how to achieve like this

[image]

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer

Comment: What is the format of your PDF ? base64 ? or an uri ?

Comment: try using `inAppBrowser` plugin

Answer (score 1):

Here is Ionic 5 Repo with PDF View without download

[Ionic 5 With ng2-PDF-Viewer](https://github.com/ChandrakantDevani/Ionic-5-with-ng2-PDF-Viewer)

How to run :

1. Clone Project
2. `npm i`
3. `npm start`

For More set PDF Options

[ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly open the PDF by using window.open

```
window.open(this.URL + name +'.pdf');
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDF.js component:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Here is a video of PDF.js component wrapped as Appery.io plugin
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeEJl7K-2H0